# IDE showing error in PHP concatenation

Tags: php

I am trying to display name and address in mail using the following piece of code this is perfect-

```
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><p>'.$admin_message['message'].'</P></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><p>Kind Regards</P></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><p>'.ucwords($finance_info['fi_schoolname']).
'<br />'.ucwords($finance_info['fi_address']).
' <br /> Email :- '.ucwords($finance_info['fi_email']).
'<br /> Contact:- '.ucwords($finance_info['fi_phoneno']).'</P>
</td>
</tr>
```

Now I want to add a image logo in it for which I am trying like this -

```
<tr>
<td align="left"><p>'.$admin_message['message'].'</P></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><p>Kind Regards</P></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><p>'
if($_SESSION['eschools']['schoollogo']!=""){ echo displayimage("images/school_logo/".$_SESSION['eschools']['schoollogo'], "140"); }
.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.
ucwords($finance_info['fi_schoolname']).'<br>
'.ucwords($finance_info['fi_address']).' <br />
Email :- '.ucwords($finance_info['fi_email']).'<br>
Contact:- '.ucwords($finance_info['fi_phoneno']).'</P></td>             
</tr>   
</table>';
```

But on Line No. 9 and 10 shows error by IDE I am using Dreamweaver. I need to know where I am doing mistake in concatenation.[image]

Regards to all

Comment: copy/paste IDE‌ error

Comment: @RezaSh Kindlt refer the image I just added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is wrong :

```
<td align="left"><p>'
if($_SESSION['eschools']['schoollogo']!=""){ echo displayimage("images/school_logo/".$_SESSION['eschools']['schoollogo'], "140"); }
```

correct code :

```
<?php
echo '
<tr>
<td align="left"><p>'.$admin_message['message'].'</P></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><p>Kind Regards</P></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><p>';
if($_['eschools']['schoollogo']!=""){ echo displayimage("images/school_logo/".$_['eschools']['schoollogo'], "140"); }
echo '    '.
ucwords($finance_info['fi_schoolname']).'<br>
'.ucwords($finance_info['fi_address']).' <br />
Email :- '.ucwords($finance_info['fi_email']).'<br>
Contact:- '.ucwords($finance_info['fi_phoneno']).'</P></td>             
</tr>   
</table>';
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind cooperation

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a semicolon after the ' after the `<p>` in line 8.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this, but it is not semicolon it is dot(.) I place it just after posting the above post, but still no relief.